# Does it imply the field is conservative?

Tags: differential-geometry, contour-integration, plane-curves, line-integrals

Physics undergraduate here :) I was wondering whether this is true:

> The line-integral of the vector field $\vec{F}=(A,B)$ is zero for **every rectangular** closed path in $\mathbb{R}^2$
> $\Rightarrow \vec{F}$ is conservative (it is zero around every path).

Does it actually hold?

Just in case, my "intuitition" below... :)

> First, the line-integral of any smooth curve can be approximating with a "staircase" on the $(x,y)$ plane ([hope it does not imply $\pi=4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/the-staircase-paradox-or-why-pi-ne4)):
>  $$\int_\text{staircase} d\vec{s}\cdot\vec{F} \equiv \sum_i\left(\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} A(x,y_i)dx + \int_{y_i}^{y_{i+1}} B(x_{i+1},y)dy\right)$$
>  $$= \sum_i\left(\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} A(x,y_i)dx + \int_{y_i}^{y_{i+1}} \left[ B(x_{i},y) + O(\Delta x)\right]dy\right) $$
>  $$= \sum_i A(x_i,y_i)\Delta x + O(\Delta x^2) + \left[B(x_i,y_i)+O(\Delta x)\right]\Delta y + O(\Delta y^2)$$
>  Taking enough steps in the staircase $\Delta x \to 0 \Rightarrow \Delta y \to 0$:
>  $$\sum_i A(x_i,y_i)\Delta x + B(x_i,y_i)\Delta y \rightarrow \int(Adx+Bdy) \equiv \int_\textrm{actual curve} d\vec{s}\cdot \vec{F}$$
>  And the summation over error terms vanishes:
>  $$\sum_i O(\Delta x^2) +O(\Delta x)\Delta y + O(\Delta y^2) \sim \frac{1}{\Delta x}\times \Delta x\Delta x \to 0$$
>  This (hopefully) shows that the line-integral of a vector field can be approximated by a staircase. Equiped with this, we may proceed to "jusify" the claim by approximating the closed curve by many rectangular paths:
>
>  [image: Clausius path]
>
>  Given that the integration over every rectangle is zero by assumption and the "staircase" approximates the actual integral, the line-integral of the smooth curve is zero.

Comment: You could use Green's theorem to justify it

Comment: Thanks! I will try to think on it :)

Comment: No, it's not true in general. If the domain of your vector field is not simply connected, it is false.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I think that's being a little hasty. Every rectangular path either means the function is well defined on all of $\Bbb{R}^2$ or just whatever its domain is. Proving that all of the paths must be $0$ from just the rectangular ones would immediately imply conservative, no notion of simply connectedness is necessary. Conservative vector fields can have non simply connected domains.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ouch, I forgot mention $\mathbb{R}^2$, good point to both of you anyways :)

Comment: @NinadMunshi you're right, my second statement was incorrectly phrased (one of the common mistakes when trying to translate theorems into everyday language).  Of course you're right that conservative vector fields can have non-simply connected domains (just take a gradient field and restrict the domain). Anyway, I'm in the process of wriitng up an answer which hopefully avoids these errors. What I meant to say is that just "simply connectedness" is a sufficient condition (though by my phrasing I made it sound like it was necessary, which is my bad).

Comment: Let F(x, y) = (g(x, y), h(x, y)) a vector field 


The field is conservative only if dg/dy = dh/dx.

Comment: @McCarter Interestingly, together with Green's thorem (as Ninad pointed out), I think this is gives the same conclusion as peek-a-boo's answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question as stated (before the edit) is no, after the edit is yes (see below).

For an explicit counter example (to your question before the edit), consider the following vector field: $F: \Bbb{R}^2 \setminus\{0\} \to \Bbb{R}^2$ defined by
\begin{align}
F(x,y) = \left( \dfrac{-y}{x^2 + y^2}, \dfrac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\right)
\end{align}
Then, a simple direct calculation shows that if $\gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$, where $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$, then
\begin{align}
\int_{\gamma} F \cdot dl &= 2\pi
\end{align}
However, you can check that the curl of this vector field is $0$ identically on all of $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$, so that by Green's/Stokes' theorem (whatever you wish to call it), if $\gamma$ is the boundary of a rectangular path (the entire rectangle, both the interior and boundary being contained inside $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$) we have that $\int_{\gamma}F \cdot dl = 0$.

---

Anyway, if you know a bit about differential forms, then here's how we can describe the situation. Let $U \subset \Bbb{R}^2$ be an open set, and $\omega = P \, dx + Q \, dy$ be a $C^1$, differential $1$-form defined on $U$. Then, the following statements are equivalent:

- $\omega$ is a closed differential form on $U$, i.e $d \omega = 0$, or equivalently, $\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \dfrac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 0$.
- For every rectangle $R \subset U$, with sides parallel to coordinate axes (i.e both the interior and the boundary of the rectangle inside $U$), if $\gamma$ denoted the boundary curve of the rectangle, then $\int_{\gamma} \omega = 0$.

Another notion is that of exactness. For that, we have the following two equivalent statements:

1. $\omega$ is an exact differential form on $U$; i.e there exists a $C^2$ function $f: U \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $\omega = df$. i.e such that $P = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $Q = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.
2. For every piecewise differentiable closed curve $\gamma$ in $U$, we have $\int_{\gamma} \omega = 0$ (not just for rectangular ones).

Note that checking whether a differential form is closed or not is very simply; just calculate two partial derivatives and see if they're equal. Checking for exactness is a much more difficult task. However, one helpful theorem is the following:

> Let $\omega$ and $U$ be defined as above. If $\omega$ is closed (i.e $d\omega = 0$) and $U$ is simply connected, then $\omega$ is exact.

So for example, if you take $U = \Bbb{R}^2$, then by the above theorem, yes, the integral vanishing over closed rectangular curves implies the integral vanishes over arbitrary (piecewise-differentiable) closed curves. For a reference regarding proofs of these claims, I suggest taking a look at [Henri Cartan's](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Elementary_Theory_of_Analytic_Functions.html?id=SlpwANmq5xQC&redir_esc=y) textbook on Complex Analysis.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, you nailed it!!!! Thanks a lot for your time and effort :)

Comment: @BrainOverflow I'm glad it was helpful. Anyway, in case you havent encountered differential forms before, the above statements can be rephrased into the language of vector fields as follows: Instead of $\omega = P \, dx + Q \, dy$, we have a vector field $F = (P,Q)$. Then, the statement $d\omega = 0$ means exactly that $\nabla \times F = 0$, while the condition $\omega = df$ means exactly that $F = \nabla f$. Also, the integral of a differential form $\int_{\gamma}\omega$ is exactly what one might write as $\int_{\gamma}F\cdot dl$. So hopefully this "translation" is helpful.

Comment: Oh nice, I never thought about these equivalences! Actually, the origin of the question is within the scope of differential thermodynamics but I thought it would be easier to translate them to line-integrals... and I was wrong xD